# Handling NullPointerException while working with ITEXTPDF for corrupt PDF files java

Tags: java, pdf, nullpointerexception, itext

I have the following block of Code to check whether a file is corrupt or not:

```
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader( inputPDFFilePath );  
        String s = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage( pdfReader, 1 );
        pdfReader.close();
```

The problem is that the file that is given as input is a corrupt PDF. On encountering this, the first line of code throws a NullPointerException. I can handle it using

try{...} catch(){...}

But the problem is I want to gracefully handle the error and deny it from throwing any exception.

Exceptions I already tried:
**InvalidPDFExcpetion
IOException
NullPointerException** (which works but as it is an unchecked exception I don't want it)

I am using iTextPDF library

Also I saw that PDF may be corrupted in different ways, here I have PDFs that do not open and show message like this

Format Error: Not a PDF or corrupted

Thanks

Comment: Which version of iText are you using? We are continuously replacing `NullPointerException`s with exceptions that tell you exactly what is wrong with the PDF. If you are using the latest version of iText, please share your PDF so that we can check the nature of the error in your PDF.

Comment: Essentially if you try to check a PDF for corruptness by using it in some PDF processor, you might get any kind of behavior from it, `Error`, `RuntimeException`, tagged `Exception`, or no exception at all (if the PDF processor does not get in touch with the corrupted PDF parts). Thus, you should catch `Throwable` and at the same time be aware that your code won't recognize every type of corruption.